# Missing views after update

Tags: views, 8

I updated my Drupal site on my local version, and everything went fine. When I synced my live version, **all of my Views that are pages (not blocks) are missing**. I manually went through the database, and it looks like their entries are still in there, but they don't show up on my Views page. I don't know if this data is incomplete or corrupted, though.

I know I could re-create the Views manually, but the better solution seems like it'd be to fix/restore the original missing Views. Is there a way to debug this? The PHP error log doesn't show anything.

**Update:** List of missing Views:

- Comments
- Content
- Custom Block Library
- Files
- Frontpage
- Media
- People
- Taxonomy Term
- Watchdog

Comment: How did you sync local and live?

Comment: `drush updatedb`?

Comment: It happened to me once that a missing module forced some views to be removed.  This can happen if the missing module is a dependency on a particular view.  Check to see that you have the same modules as your production server.

Comment: All my modules are the same on both (ie the files and the Extend pages).

Comment: Everything but the sites folder is in git. I just pull onto the live server. My database is already updated. Although FWIW, I can't install drush with composer on the live server because it consumes my entire memory allowance and then dies.